# Motorola G4 Play keeps on disconnecting when in USB debugging mode

Tags: android, usb, adb, device, motorola

I have a Motorla G4 Play device for testing.

It works just fine, the USB connection is OK and I can view files, photos etc on my Ubuntu workstation.

The problem is when I turn on *"USB debugging"* from the developer options view.

The device goes into a connected-disconnected loop. It connects for a second (the PC detects it, the Android-bug icon appears in the top-left corner of the device screen) and then it disconnects. And then connects again etc. etc.

I have no clue how to debug this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why no love for this question? It's at the top of the search results for my query and matches my problem exactly.

Answer (score 3):

If you look in your USB connectivity settings and your phone is set up for (USB charge only), it may try and draw more current from your USB port. Usually a normal USB port should be able to supply anywhere around 500mA and in case your device tries to draw "more", your motherboard will likely open a protection circuit and cut the power.

I would suggest trying another port, trying to disable USB charging and if that doesn't fix it, try using a better USB cable with greater AWG rating (it is very unlikely for that to be the case anyway).

Good luck

Comment: I'm betting this *is* the correct answer and that a powered USB hub will fix the problem. I've also heard that driver updates will solve it. However, it persists despite having the latest `adb` installed on my linux box.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by plugging it in one of the back USB ports.

Just try out if it works on other USB ports.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what could cause this.

Comment: This question is dated, but I would try an external, powered USB port.